# ListView adapter behaves strangely

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, listview-adapter

`ListView` adapter does strange things. Method `getChecked()` (adapter code shown below) does not return the value that I expect. As if he is late by one step.

For understanding, I will explain: I am using a custom `ListView`, every item contain one `CheckBox` (and other `Views`). I want to make when I press the button to show the position of the checked elements. This makes the method `getChecked()`.
But the following happens: I check the 2nd and the 4th list items and click on the button, the result - [], then I check the 5th item, the result - [2, 4], then I clean all `CheckBoxes`, result [2, 4, 5] when I click the button again, I receive - []. Result is late by one step.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

private boolean isCheckBoxVisible;
private View view;

private int[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN};
private int currentMaleColor;
private int currentFemaleColor;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    isCheckBoxVisible = false;
    setColors();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contacts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private Contact getContact(int position) {
    return (Contact) getItem(position);
}

public void setCheckBoxVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
    isCheckBoxVisible = isVisible;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
    }

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_box);
    if (isCheckBoxVisible) {
        cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    Contact c = getContact(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_name)).setText(c.getName() + " " + c.getSurname());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_img)).setImageBitmap(c.getPhoto());

    if (c.getSex().equals("Man")) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(currentMaleColor);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(currentFemaleColor);
    }

    boolean isCheck = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_box)).isChecked();
    contacts.get(position).setChecked(isCheck);
    return view;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getChecked() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    ArrayList<Integer> IDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        if (c.isChecked()) IDs.add(c.getID());
    }
    return IDs;
}

private void setColors() {
    int colorM = Integer.parseInt(MainActivity.sp.getString("lp_colorM", "0"));
    int colorW = Integer.parseInt(MainActivity.sp.getString("lp_colorW", "0"));

    currentMaleColor = colors[colorM];
    currentFemaleColor = colors[colorW];
}

}
```

In my activity I use my adapter, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contacts);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My button's code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = adapter.getChecked();
Toast.makeText(this, al.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What do you think about this? I will be glad of any help.

Comment: `contacts.get(position).setChecked(isCheck);` updates the status if the contact only when the view is refreshed, not when the view is clicked. Use a checkedchangedlistener on your CB to detect the change immediatly.

Comment: Good idea, **njzk2**. I'll try to do it. But then I have a question - why now method getChecked () gives the result of late? I think that this method should not work now at all if the adapter is not updated.

Comment: because getChecked returns the result of the call to `setChecked` which is delayed by the fact that it is only updated based on the status of the convertView. (it will give even weirder results if you have enough items to scroll.)

Comment: Hmm ... I will answer you when check how it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the advice of njzk2, I changed it:

```
boolean isCheck = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_box)).isChecked();
contacts.get(position).setChecked(isCheck);
```

At this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_box);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        contacts.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
    }
});
```

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get State of view if convertView == null

```
 if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_viewproduct, null);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

// set the data to view from holder

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is the class - Holder? What do you mean?

Comment: `view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = (View) convertView.getTag();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but want say you can use below

```
private void setColors() {
        int colorM = Integer.parseInt(MainActivity.sp.getString("lp_colorM", "0"));
        int colorW = Integer.parseInt(MainActivity.sp.getString("lp_colorW", "0"));

        if(colorM < 5){
            currentMaleColor = colors[colorM];
        }

        if(colorW < 5){
            currentFemaleColor = colors[colorM];
        }  
    }
```

To answer your question look at the view holder pattern
http://ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/

Comment: Kevin Crain, thank you very much for your comment. For some reason I did not pay attention to it before, but now corrected my code.

Comment: Its a pleasure, you could use colorM < colors.length, so if you add more colors you only change in one place :)